# Proving equivalence of two different induction definitions

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction, natural-numbers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtmrd.jpg)I'm reading Stillwell's Elements of Algebra (see screen). I'm struggling with proving the equivalence of the versions of induction, specifically the step (II=>III).

If I take T = {1,2}.  T is a subset of N and 1 is its least member.  Then looking at the line II=>III.  "Let S = N-T" (so S={0,3,4,...}). "If T has no least member then 0 is a member of S" (T has a least member so this part doesn't apply), "otherwise 0 is the least member of T" No! 1 is the least member of T!  What am I missing?

Comment: If you plan to post more here, learn to use mathjax and avoid images of text. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

The sentence that puzzles you is indeed awkwardly written. A better way to say it might be

> If $T$ has no least member then it can't contain $0$ (which would be
> the least) so $0$ must be in $S$.

The argument then goes on to show that knowing $0 \in S$ leads to a contradiction.